# InvalidIdentifierUri on creating AAD application

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an azure ad application using powershell script:

```
        $appIdGuid = New-Guid
        $graphApp = New-AzureADApplication  -DisplayName $graphAppDisplayName `
                                                -IdentifierUris "api://$appIDGuid" `
                                                -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
                                                -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess `
                                                -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                                -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $false `
                                                -PublicClient $false
```

On running the above script, I get the error:

```
New-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing NewApplication 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The application identifier uri '[api://b0129570-1d70-4c1a-8eb8-6301c0f4dc2f]' is invalid.
RequestId: aaaccbaa-bab2-4ff0-bb4b-aeacfa3863c5
DateTimeStamp: Tue, 04 Jan 2022 01:11:57 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - identifierUris, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidIdentifierUri
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Scripts\Set-GraphCredentialsAzureADApplication.ps1:142 char:21
+ ... $graphApp = New-AzureADApplication    -DisplayName $graphAppDisplayNa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADApplication], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewApplication
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would think that an api URI needs either the appID or tenantID as part of the URL. Do you have any control over the actual appID that gets generated? Docs that I found specify appID as an attribute that is created by Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ***AdminOfThings*** has already mentioned in the comments , you can only put the ***clientId of the new app registration or the tenantid*** as the `identifierUri` in ***AAD with Premium License***.

***So , as a solution you can use something like below :***

```
$graphAppDisplayName = "testapp"
$App=New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $graphAppDisplayName -AvailableToOtherTenants $false -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $false -PublicClient $false
$id=$App.AppId
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.objectId -IdentifierUris "api://$id"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are $App.AppId and $App.ApplicationId the same?